# Can I Daisy-chain if my laptop only has HDMI output?

Tags: daisychaining

My HP Pavilion laptop only has HDMI output & I'm wanting to Daisy-chain to two external monitors.  My monitor, Philips Brilliance 241B7, manual says it needs DP or USB-C input to Daisy-chain.

Can I get a HDMI to DP adaptor & will this allow Daisy-chaining?

Thanks Alan

Comment: HDMI doesn’t support daisy chaining displays, using a hDMI to DisplayPort cable doesn’t change that fact.

Comment: You should be able to get an HP dock for the laptop that supports two external monitors.

Answer (score 1):

DisplayPort is designed (since DP 1.2) to carry multiple display data streams in one physical connection. This is called [Multi-stream Transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multi-Stream_Transport_(MST)) (MST). It is what enables DisplayPort Daisy Chaining. Basically, your graphics card can “see” all displays connected even though some are not directly connected.

USB-C (the form factor) features multiple modes (“Alt Mode”), one of which is USB + DisplayPort.

HDMI unfortunately is not designed for connecting multiple displays. So even if you use an active HDMI to DisplayPort adapter, you could only connect a single display.

However, as John mentioned in the comments, if your laptop supports a docking station using some sort of proprietary connector, you may be able to connect multiple displays this way. Even though a DisplayPort connector may not be available externally, it is often used with docking stations.